# R is returning false with == when the two paramaters are true

Tags: r, matrix, equality

Here I have a 3 x 3 matrix and have calculated the determinant of the matrix and the determinant of the transpose of the matrix (which should be and are the same according to the code) but when comparing them to check if they are equal I am getting an output of false.

This is also true if I assign the values to other variables and check them.

Here is my code:

```
matrixTest <- matrix(
  c(c(1,5,7),c(1,2,6),c(8,2,6)),
  ncol = 3,
)

det(matrixTest)
det(t(matrixTest))

det(matrixTest) == det(t(matrixTest))
```

Output from R studio when running this block:

```
> det(matrixTest)
[1] 112
> det(t(matrixTest))
[1] 112
> 
> det(matrixTest) == det(t(matrixTest))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I suspect the same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: Yep. Try `sprintf("%.15f", det(matrixTest))` and 
`sprintf("%.15f", det(t(matrixTest)))`  You'll see that the two numbers are slightly different many digits down due to how floating point numbers work. In a situation like this, it's more informative to use `all.equal(det(matrixTest), det(t(matrixTest)))`, since it allows for some imprecision in how the number is stored.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to floating point approximation:

```
det(matrixTest) - det(t(matrixTest))
## [1] -9.947598e-14
```

Use `all.equal` to compare whether two objects are equal to within a tolerance.  See `?all.equal` for more information.

```
all.equal(det(matrixTest), det(t(matrixTest)))
## [1] TRUE
```

In this particular case since the elements are all integer we know the result must be integer so another appraoch is to round both sides:

```
round(det(matrixTest)) == round(det(t(matrixTest)))
## [1] TRUE
```

There is also `zapsmall`:

```
zapsmall(det(matrixTest)) == zapsmall(det(t(matrixTest)))
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Do you know of any resources where I can read about the way R handles situations like this? To learn how to avoid it in future.

Comment: This is how floating point works in all languages, not just R, so any general discussion of floating point should do.  Maybe Wikipedia's entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: See informative answer from the question I linked above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/6851825